# Deploy under subdirectory instead /

Tags: reactjs, apache, ant-design-pro

I would like to deploy ant design pro, under subfolder,
eg: http://localhost`/ant`
but ant still using / instead /ant for css and js resources

[image: Google Chrome Console]

Comment: Where did you deploy your website to?

Comment: c:\wamp64\www\ant